# groovy maps unexpected looping behaviour

Tags: loops, groovy, scope

These two code blocks are almost identical, the resultant data structures were expected to be the same.

`slabels` is a map of sorted date-time values on docker-tag keys.
`ind` is a sequential index value to be used later.
`dtags` is a map that is being composed here.
`properties` is a map of maps being composed here.

Example A

```
        def dtags = [:];
        slabels.each {
          ind ++
          dtags << ['lastModified': it.value]
          dtags << ['seq': ind]
          println it.key + ": " + dtags
          properties.put("$it.key", dtags)
        }
        println properties
```

```
Result: println it.key + ": " + dtags
1.30: [lastModified:2020-02-12T10:31:19.107+0000, seq:1]
1.29: [lastModified:2020-02-11T15:44:49.658+0000, seq:2]
1.28: [lastModified:2020-02-10T09:22:49.010+0000, seq:3]

Result: println properties
[1.30:[lastModified:2019-12-10T17:14:10.672+0000, seq:22],
1.29:[lastModified:2019-12-10T17:14:10.672+0000, seq:22],
1.28:[lastModified:2019-12-10T17:14:10.672+0000, seq:22]]
```

Here `properties."$it.key" = dtags` produces the same result.

Example B

```
        def dtags = [:];
        slabels.each {
          ind ++
          dtags << ['lastModified': it.value]
          dtags << ['seq': ind]
          println it.key + ": " + dtags
          properties."$it.key" = ['lastModified': it.value, 'seq': ind]
        }
        println properties
```

```
Result: println it.key + ": " + dtags
1.30: [lastModified:2020-02-12T10:31:19.107+0000, seq:1]
1.29: [lastModified:2020-02-11T15:44:49.658+0000, seq:2]
1.28: [lastModified:2020-02-10T09:22:49.010+0000, seq:3]

Result: println properties
[1.30:[lastModified:2020-02-12T10:31:19.107+0000, seq:1],
1.29:[lastModified:2020-02-11T15:44:49.658+0000, seq:2],
1.28:[lastModified:2020-02-10T09:22:49.010+0000, seq:3]]
```

Please note that the `println it.key + ": " + dtags` results are the same yet the `println properties` differ.  For clarity the example B is the desired result.

If I define `dtags` inside the loop, then that resolves the issue and may even be a clue.

However, in example A, `dtags` **seems** to be being used twice in the same scope producing different results.  The short question, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In example A all 3 props will reference the same map `dtags`. Inside the loop you are changing the keys (content) inside this map, but the map itself remains the same.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put a reference to `dtags` into your `properties` in your first code example - therefor the last assignment to `dtags` is the only one remaining and all `properties` are the same.

It's hard to tell, what the overarching problem to solve here actually is (the code is very convoluted), but I assume, you would get more idiotmatic code by using `eachWithIndex`/`collect`/...

Comment: I get it now, thank you.

The goal is to operate on a number of items referenced by date, predicated on 'how old they are' and 'position in the sequence of items'.

My thought is to create a data structure which came be passed around from method to method so that items state is consistent and items don't need to be re-evaluated before setting up each method.

I will look for more idiotmatic code as you suggest.  Again, thank you.